# How to convert a named list of named vectors to a data.frame conveniently?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Suppose I have the following named list of named vectors:

```
structure(list(var1 = structure(c(-0.59588185761272, -1.40360179042903,
-0.930940964040855, 0.627327161612272, 2.5718263501814, -0.494398712878508
), .Names = c("W", "X", "J", "V", "Y", "A")), var2 = structure(0.845082248473655, .Names = "K"),
    var3 = structure(c(-0.0445511021832538, 1.29597344526442), .Names = c("B",
    "C"))), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))

# $var1
#          W          X          J          V          Y          A 
# -0.5958819 -1.4036018 -0.9309410  0.6273272  2.5718264 -0.4943987 
# 
# $var2
#         K 
# 0.8450822 
# 
# $var3
#          B          C 
# -0.0445511  1.2959734
```

How do I derive a `data.frame` of values, names of vectors and names of lists. derived output looks like this:

```
#       values vec var.name
# 1 -0.5958819   W     var1
# 2 -1.4036018   X     var1
# 3 -0.9309410   J     var1
# 4  0.6273272   V     var1
# 5  2.5718264   Y     var1
# 6 -0.4943987   A     var1
# 7  0.8450822   K     var2
# 8 -0.0445511   B     var3
# 9  1.2959734   C     var3
```

I tried stack but it ignores the names of vectors.

Comment: If I understand you right, `stack` doesn't ignore the names of the vectors, but puts them into the rownames. So maybe a two liner: `df <- stack(df);  df$vec <-  row.names(df)`. or a third line for re-arranging. (and maybe `row.names(df) <- seq_along(df[,1])` to reset row.names if that is important).

Comment: @lmo, if there are duplicated names for different vectors (for, example if we change B in var3 to W, which appeared in names of var1 vector), the rownames will be sequential intergers.

Comment: In that case, another two liner: `dfNew <- stack(df); df$vec <- unlist(lapply(df, names))` would work.

Comment: @lmo, thanks. This is better than my solution. What I tried is `df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df, stack));
df2$var.name <- rep(names(df), lengths(df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# OPs data
d <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(-0.59588185761272, -1.40360179042903,
-0.930940964040855, 0.627327161612272, 2.5718263501814, -0.494398712878508
), .Names = c("W", "X", "J", "V", "Y", "A")), var2 = structure(0.845082248473655, .Names = "K"),
    var3 = structure(c(-0.0445511021832538, 1.29597344526442), .Names = c("B",
    "C"))), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))

# Solution 
d <- unlist(d)
data.frame(value = d, 
           vec = gsub(".*\\.", "", names(d)), 
           var.name =  gsub("\\..*", "", names(d)))
```

Comment: This works for this data! Just to mention that if the names of list or names of vectors contains '.' the `vec` and `var.name` would be difficult to extract from unlisted data.

Comment: @mt1022, true, but it's easy to `gsub` and change names of list or vectors (different question).

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to your two-step solution using `do.call(rbind` + `stack` and then adding in "var.name" would be to use `rbindlist` from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(L, stack), idcol = TRUE)
##     .id     values ind
## 1: var1 -0.5958819   W
## 2: var1 -1.4036018   X
## 3: var1 -0.9309410   J
## 4: var1  0.6273272   V
## 5: var1  2.5718264   Y
## 6: var1 -0.4943987   A
## 7: var2  0.8450822   K
## 8: var3 -0.0445511   B
## 9: var3  1.2959734   C
```

Comment: Wow, I never notice this argument! I thought `rbindlist` is just a more efficient `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternative solutions in comment that I would like to summarize it here:

from lmo:

```
df_new <- stack(df)
df_new$vec <- unlist(lapply(df, names))
```

My solution. `stack` works on a named vector too (by calling as.list):

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df, stack))
df2$var.name <- rep(names(df), lengths(df))
```